# Criterion for detecting rank-deficiency via QR decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I apologize in advance if this is an ill-posed question -- I'd appreciate advice on what pieces are missing as much as an answer.

I'm solving a system like $P \approx X Y^T$, where P is a large sparse matrix, and X and Y are a low-rank (rank $k$) factorization of P. I need to solve, for example, for a row of X, $X_u$, given $P_u$ and $Y$. I'm approximating with $X_u = P_u Y (Y^T Y)^{-1}$.

I'm computing a solution for $(Y^T Y)^{-1}$ with a QR decomposition. But the matrix may be rank deficient or very nearly so. If it's nearly so, the solution for $X_u$ can be, for example, quite large -- a "bad" answer in the sense that it's much larger than any other row of $X$.

I'm examining the diagonal of $R$ in the decomposition. If it ends in 0 -- or very small values, less than some $\epsilon$ -- I conclude that $Y^T Y$ was rank deficient ($k$ was too large). This appears to generally work.

But, picking a smallish $\epsilon$ doesn't work in all cases. In some cases I find the diagonal elements are overall quite large, with values towards the end much smaller but not nearly 0 (i.e., not even < 1). I'd like to reject these cases too since they produce "bad" answers.

A single threshold is obviously not a suitable criterion. I'm looking for guidance on how to reliably detect this situation. Or better frame the question.

Comment: Tough problem. Maybe your application suggests some relevant criteria? How are you computing the QR decomposition? Householder is faster, Givens is a little more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. This is in Java and I'm using Commons Math. The implementation (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/QRDecomposition.java/) uses Householder reflections. The diagonal of R is plainly decreasing, but I'm having a hard time quantifying where it becomes "very small" since no absolute threshold seems sufficient. It feels like there must be some mathematically correct-er approach.

Comment: I think it depends more on the levels of 'noise' in your application?

Comment: If so I am not smart enough to see how.. I'm not speaking about quantizing $P$ and rounding small values to 0, but evaluating the diagonal of $R$ in the QR decomposition.

Comment: Sorry, I have no good suggestions. The QR decomposition is 'well-behaved' numerically, so (roughly speaking), rank ambiguities reflect ambiguities in the data. That was all I meant by 'noise' above...

Comment: The QR decomposition is numerically well behaved meaning that the Q and the R are well within a small numerical resolution. But when you calculate using the inverse of the R, the result does not behave in the same numerically stable manner.
If accuracy is important, then the singular value decomposition is the only way to go.

Comment: Are you using pivoted QR? pivoted QR is a type of rank revealing decomposition, which is not true for simple QR decomposition.